# PhP not embedding in html

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get a use php in an html box, but it isn't working.  Here's what i'm putting in: (there's some javascript too)

```
<?php
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$data = json_encode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . $data . ');';
?>
<script>
var myip="<?php echo $data ?>"
alert(myip)
</script>
```

And here's what's appearing on the website:

```
<?php header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); 
$data = json_encode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); 
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . $data . ');'; ?>
```

Well, that and an alert box that says:

```
<?php echo $data ?>
```

Comment: what is the extension of the file?

Comment: So none of the PHP is being interpreted by the server? This probably has nothing to do with your code and more to do with the configuration of your server. Do you have PHP installed? Does your filename end with `.php`?

Comment: Oops.  I did forget to use the .php extension.  Thanks!  *facepalm*

Answer (score -2):

You have to put a semicolon:

```
<?php echo $data; ?>
```

You want to put this into a textbox?

Do this:

```
<input type="text" id="someid" name="somename" value="<?php echo $data; ?>" />
```

Are you sure that in $data is anything?

Comment: that shouldn't be necessary

Comment: I always put there a semicolon. To avoid any problems.

Comment: If this *was* the problem, the whole thing would fail with a SYNTAX ERROR; since it doesn't do that, it's not the problem.

Comment: Well, that's right, but I do it always to avoid problems.